# MySQL Multiple Conditions in Grouped Data

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to see how many users have clicked on an ad campaign and signed up afterwards.

My Logging table has the columns IP, UserID, and Data (this has the `$_GET` info like `utm_source = newsletter`). A user may click a link in newsletter and then later sign up on my website (which is indicated when they have a UserID that is not blank). I am trying to group by IP and then see if any IP has had an instance of `utm` in `Data` column and a non-blank UserID (but note that these 2 criteria may be true on different rows)

Currently I have:

```
SELECT `ip`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(`UserID`)) FROM `Logs`
WHERE `Data` LIKE '%utm%'
GROUP BY `ip`
```

However this is not correct because the WHERE statement filters entire rows, not within the grouped data.

---

Let me clarify this further.

If table looks like

```
IP              UserID     Data
12.34.56.78     abcde      
12.34.56.78                utm_source = email
87.65.43.21     xxxxx
19.28.11.11     random
19.28.11.11     random
19.28.11.11                utm_source = newsletter
```

I want the output to look like

```
IP              UserID     Data
12.34.56.78     abcde      utm_source = email
19.28.11.11     random     utm_source = newsletter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `HAVING` clause, *which treats similar to a `WHERE` condition for an aggregation*, principally in order to provide getting a concatenated non-null `Data` and `UserID` values at the same time per each `ip` value along with individually using `GROUP_CONCAT()` function such as

```sql
SELECT `ip`, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
                        CASE
                        WHEN `Data` LIKE '%utm%'
                        THEN
                             `Data`
                         END
                      ) AS Datas,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
                             `UserID`
                      ) AS UserIDs
  FROM Logs
 GROUP BY `ip`
HAVING MAX(`UserID`) IS NOT NULL AND MAX(`Data`) IS NOT NULL
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=114506fcd1b92a845af9eab100c0fe4e)</kbd>

Comment: Got an error `#1111 - Invalid use of group function`

Comment: Thats not quite it. Your code of `WHEN Data LIKE '%utm%' AND UserID IS NOT NULL`  does not match my needs. Sometimes there may be a row where data is like utm but userid is null. they may register at a later point (and there may be no utm)

Comment: @Bijan yess, now it's OK along with the sample data and the desired result set.